# How to customize vue-json-excel?

Tags: excel, vue.js, vue-component

I'm using [`vue-json-excel`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-json-excel) plugin to download a `table` and some contents into an `Excel` document.

What I need to know is that whether there are any methods which I can use to customize the `excel` document - changing the `background color` of a `cell`, font colors, adding table borders etc.

Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

use other library because vue-json-excel doesnt have any customizability

just download https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx with **PRO** version

Comment: they have given some properties https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-json-excel#props-list in `vue-json-excel`. Thank you for the information about `js-xlsx` @Bagaskara.